# Math rock chord progression analysis

Tags: chord-progressions

I have been given this chord progression I have to analyse:

```
Em9 | F#m7 F#7/G | Bm11 | Cmaj7 Dmaj7 | Em9 (loop around)
```

I've got around to set E as the root since it's the one that sounds the most stable. So the progression would go like this:

```
Im9 | IIm7 II7 | Vm11 | bVImaj7 bVIImaj7 | Im9
```

Excluding the colours, and taking F#7/G as a passing chord, I'd say this is in E aeolian (or E natural minor). But the 7ths are inconsistent and getting me confused.

How would you analyse this?

Answer (score 1):

Without listening to the actual song it is hard to tell where the tonal center lies.

In E minor you wouldn't have neither `F#m` nor `Dmaj7`, but rather `F#dim`/`F#m7b5` and `D7`.

If you look at it from a D major / B minor perspective, everything is diatonic besides the passing `F#7/G` and the `Cmaj7`, that can be seen as a bVII / myxolidian moment or as a simple planing back to D.

(btw in roman numerals notations you use small letters in favour of the `m` modifier, so `v` over `Vm`.)

Comment: I know there are two "schools" about roman numeral notation... This is how I've learned it so that's the way I usually write them :)

Comment: Maybe I can get an audio sample or sheets... I'll try to get some.

Comment: There are many types and styles of roman numeral notation, and none is "the right one". Some books don't use the "small letter" approach at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would view this as a chord progression in E minor (or, given the C#'s, could be in Dorian mode) which, put in Roman numerals, would be

i-ii-V7/v-v-VI-VII